# angular 2 material 2 removable md-chip

Tags: angular, angular-material2

Could someone help me understand how to make make an angular 2 material 2 chip removable like the angularjs material chips.  I can't seem to find any working examples.  Is this feature even supported in material 2?
Thanks,
Ali

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They're still in PR: https://github.com/angular/material2/pull/2476

You can try what's already there, and then update upon stable release.

Comment: Fair enough.  Do you know how I would go about using a prerelease version of material?  Right now I am adding material via npm/package.json.

Comment: I've ended up doing my own component & directive for same. :(

Comment: @Ali just install the latest snapshots from master with `npm install --save angular/material2-builds angular/cdk-builds`